# Dispatching multiple actions in redux duplicates the state parameters

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have used created two actions and their respective reducers. When i dispatch any single action, both actions initial states are being saved to state where the parameters of the states are duplicated.

actions/index.js

```
import { COUNTER_CHANGE, UPDATE_NAVIGATION } from "../constants";

export function changeCount(count) {

  return {
    type: COUNTER_CHANGE,
    payload: count,
  };
}

export function updateNavigation(obj) {

  return {
    type: UPDATE_NAVIGATION,
    payload: obj,
  };
}
```

reducers.js

```
import { COUNTER_CHANGE, UPDATE_NAVIGATION } from "../constants";
import logger from "redux-logger";

const initialState = {
  count: 0,
  navigation: {},
};

export const countReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case COUNTER_CHANGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const updateNavigation = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_NAVIGATION:
      return {
        ...state,
        navigation: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
// export default countReducer;
```

reducer/index.js

```
import { countReducer, updateNavigation } from "../reducers/countReducer";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  countReducer,
  updateNavigation,
});

export default allReducers;
```

Dispatching actions

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.props.updateNavigation(navigation);
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { ...bindActionCreators({ changeCount, updateNavigation }, dispatch) };
};
```

As we can see here I have triggered only updateNavigation action. But it updates states with duplicate parameters in redux state as shown below

[image]

The expected o/p will be

countReducer : {count : 0}
updateNavigation : {navigation :{}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of state for each reducer is incorrect. See [defining-state-shape](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers#defining-state-shape) docs and try this:

```js
export const countReducer = (state = { count: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case COUNTER_CHANGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const updateNavigation = (state = { navigation: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_NAVIGATION:
      return {
        ...state,
        navigation: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```js
import { countReducer, updateNavigation } from "../reducers/countReducer";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  countReducer,
  updateNavigation,
});

const store = createStore(allReducers);
console.log(store.getState());
```

Output:

```sh
{ countReducer: { count: 0 }, updateNavigation: { navigation: {} } }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.. It worked. So we dont have to define an initialState at the start..

Answer (score 0):

In your action/index.js

```
import { COUNTER_CHANGE, UPDATE_NAVIGATION } from "../constants";

export function changeCount(count) {

  dispatch( {
    type: COUNTER_CHANGE,
    payload: count,
  });
}

export function updateNavigation(obj) {

  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_NAVIGATION,
    payload: obj,
  });
}
```

Dispatch the data without returning it